# c++ pointer error (access violation)

Tags: c++, pointers, access-violation

I am new to C++ and think I am probably doing something I shouldn't be with pointers. I've checked tons of resources, but just can't find the problem. After debugging for a while it looks like this is the problem code.

```
writeHeader(outFile, width, height); 
for (int row=0; row < width+1; row++){ // row == 0 is the bottom row
    for (int col=0; col < height+1; col++){ // col == 0 is the leftmost column
    Color c =  getPixel(row, col);
    outFile.write((char*)c.blue, 1);
    outFile.write((char*)c.green, 1);
    outFile.write((char*)c.red, 1);
    }
}
```

can anyone see what is wrong?

The getPixel method looks like this.

```
Color BMPCanvas::getPixel(int x, int y){
if (x<=width && y<=height){
        return image[y*width + x];
    }
    return Color(0,0,0);
}
```

EDIT: I changed the above code to:

```
    for (int row=0; row < width; row++){ // row == 0 is the bottom row
        for (int col=0; col < height; col++){ // col == 0 is the leftmost column
        Color c =  getPixel(row, col);
        unsigned char green = c.green, blue = c.blue, red = c.red;
        outFile.write((char*)&blue, 1);
        outFile.write((char*)&green, 1);
        outFile.write((char*)&red, 1);
        }
    }
```

which I believe fixed one of the problems, but I am still getting a memory error. Green blue and red refer to numbers referring to their color value such as (255,255,255).

I truly appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you mean `(char*)&c.blue` instead of `(char*)c.blue`? As written now you're reinterpreting a value, a byte probably, as a pointer. Or simply `&c.blue`, since `c.blue` is probably a `char`.

Comment: I realized that just a moment ago. I think that was indeed the problem though. Thanks. Still seem to be getting a memory can't be accessed problem though, although I think it has to do with the getPixel method more than the top code now.

Comment: You're probably mixing `row` and `col`. `row` should go vertically (height), and `col` horizontally (width). Right now you have them mixed up.

Comment: I.e. you're passing the `row` to `x` in `getPixel` and `col` to `y` which makes zero sense. It should probably be `col` to `x` and `row` to `y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be you have an "off by one" error.  C++ arrays are zero based and so when you have an array with 10 slots you iterate from 0 to 9, not 0 to 10.

Try changing getPixel to this:

```
Color BMPCanvas::getPixel(int x, int y){
if (x<width && y<height){
        return image[y*width + x];
    }
    return Color(0,0,0);
}
```

And your other loop to this:

```
for (int row=0; row < width; row++){ // row == 0 is the bottom row
    for (int col=0; col < height; col++){ // col == 0 is the leftmost column
```